# How to suppress warnings about unused variables in C++?

Tags: c++

How can one suppress warnings compiler generates about unused variables in a c++ program?

I am using g++ compiler

Comment: "How can one?" Why does one want to?

Comment: By using them? If a variable is unused, why can't you just delete its definition? You may well have a good answer to this, and/or that answer may affect the best approach to use.

Comment: I would look at the -W flag options.

Comment: There is also `__attribute__((unused))` if you want make it stand out.

Comment: I would initialize the variables personally.

Comment: You can also omit function parameter identifiers if the values aren't used: maybe make them a `/* */`-surrounded comment for documentation value if sensible.

Comment: @MooingDuck That would instead cause a *set-but-unused* variable warning (if enabled).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compile with the `-Wno-unused-variable` option.

See the [GCC documentation on Warning Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) for more information.

The `-Wno-__` options turn off the options set by `-W__`. Here we are turning off [`-Wunused-variable`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunused_002dvariable-333).

Also, you can apply the `__attribute__((unused))` to the variable (or function, etc.) to suppress this warning on a case-by-case basis. Thanks [Jesse Good](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906773/jesse-good) for mentioning this.

Answer (score 11):

Put in a cast to void:

```
int unused;
(void)unused;
```

Comment: The cast to `void` is the idiomatic way of marking a variable as *used* but with no side effects. +1

Comment: especially useful if the given variable is used in conditional part (for example a function parameter used only in some debug log)

Answer (score 2):

To remove these warnings I make a **macro** that can be used throughout my project:

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)
```